# How to combine Django session validation with REST token validation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

So in my general DJANGO page, I use session validation, and validated user has a cookie stored. Now I expand my project with REST, with REST, I use token validation, when user login on client side, I will use REST token validation to validate, and then put a djangotoken into cookie for persistent.

Client side can read the djangotoken on next check. But how do I mix the two, for example, I have logged in traditionally, and now on client page, how do I read from cookie to check if the user is logged in already?